# Finding the Local Maximum and Minimum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given $f(x,y) = 6y - y^3 - 4x^2y$ and asked to find the critical points. After I have found those I'm asked to find D= $f_{xx}f_{yy} - f_{xy}^2$ and to decide whether I have a local max, min, or a saddle point.

I found the critical points pretty easily. $f_x(x,y) = 8xy$ and $f_y(x,y)=6-3y^2-4x^2$
I set them equal to zero and solved for x and y. The critical points that I got where $ (\sqrt{3/2}, 0), (-\sqrt{3/2}, 0), (0, \sqrt{2}), (0, -\sqrt{2}) $

Then I calculated $f_{xx}=8y$ and $f_{yy}=-6y$ and $f_{xy}=8x$. So, the equation for D that I got was $D= -48y^2 - 64x^2$
This is where I get lost. When I plug the points into D I keep getting -96 for all of them. Therefore, I thought they were all saddle points. However, this is incorrect. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing incorrect?

Comment: It's probably just a computational error. Just go through it again step by step,extra carefully.

Comment: Check your signs. Otherwise it all looks good.

Comment: I keep checking my work but I don't see anything

Comment: $f_{x}=-8xy$ seems to be the problem (sign error) from which other errors follow, I guess.